# Fortran debugging in VSCode, array slicing

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gdb

How do I inspect data with array slices in VSCode for fortran, I tried `var(6,:,:,:)`, but this does not work as I get the error, "-var-create: unable to create variable object"

The compiler I use is gfortran
Plugins are : Fortran breakpoint support, GDB Debugger - Beyond and Modern Fortran

Comment: What debugger/plugin are you using? Please do not just write "it does not work", say what happened when you tried it.